# Position bigger child out of and above parent?

Tags: css

What I have now is [this page](http://www.formkid.com/f/kavoir/post-your-jobs-to-xianjobs-com/).

And I want the section title block "Employer Information" to be 40px wider than it naturally is, breaking out of its parent, as shown in [this image](http://postimage.org/image/fkmeju4rp/).

Thus far I tried:

```
.content form ol {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 50;
}

.content form ol .section {
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    width: 110%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

And tried several other parent elements to be position:relative but it never worked.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main` class has `overflow: hidden`, so it's masking the parts that are outside of it. Try your code with `overflow: visible` on `.main`.

Also Use `position: relative` in `.section`, or else it will be taken out of natural flow and the rest of the content jumps up behind it.

Answer (score 1):

As "freejost" said, remove `overflow:hidden` in the class `main` and add the style `position:relative` for `li`

i.e

```
#submit_form li{
position:relative;
}
#empInfo {
left: 0;
position: absolute;
right: -20px;
top: 0;
}
```

The HTML edits are :

```
<div id="empInfo" class="description section" >
<h2>Employer Information</h2>
<div>General information regarding the employer business or organization.</div>
</div>
```

This should fix it.. there are a few other edits which u have to make to make it work,but this should get you at a comfortable level